# Updating an Android Fragment's ListView from the background

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, android-fragments

I've been searching for the past few days, but have had no success, so I'm posting this question in the hopes someone can answer it.

Setup (Using android-support-library-v4, revision 12):

I have 1 Main Activity with a ViewPager.

I have 1 Fragment Class, called DataFragmentClass which consists of a ListView. 
This fragment class loads data off the internet asynchronously and displays it in the listview. However, this fragment class can load two types of data, called DataTypeA and DataTypeB.

What I do is create two instances of this fragment in my main activity like so:

```
Fragment[] mFragmentList = new Fragment[2];
mFragmentList[0] = DataFragmentClass.newInstance(Modes.DataTypeA);
mFragmentList[1] = DataFragmentClass.newInstance(Modes.DataTypeB);
```

I then pass this array to my ViewPager, which works fine.

After being created, the Fragments will begin to async load the data:

```
    @Override  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genericlistview, container, false);

        DataProvider mDataProvider = new DataProvider(this.getActivity());
        mDataProvider.addListener(mDataResponseAdapter);

        return view;  
    }
```

The first data load everything is fine - DataTypeA will load in Fragment1 and DataTypeB will load in Fragment2.

However, any subsequent loads result in the data 'spilling over'. All the data (Type A and B) is now loaded in Fragment2.

I've narrowed the problem down to the ListView updates.

What I do is:

```
        Runnable updateListView = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.add(myNewData);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }           
        };


    DataFragmentClass.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(updateListView);
```

I think something goes wrong at these points:

1. When posting the runnable on the UI thread.
2. When the remote server returns the data.

Any suggestions at all would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of class is the "DataProvider"?

Comment: 'DataProvider' is an asynchronous data loading class - it loads large amounts of data of the internet and returns it via a callback.